# What is the name of this manga which is featured in the credits page of a manga scanlated by Serenus Dreamers?

Tags: kiss-and-never-cry

[image: Credits page]

I am looking for the manga in this picture. I already know it is not *7th Period is a Secret*, it's just a credits page in this series, but I can't seem to find the manga where the image originally comes from.

The credits page comes from a scanlator group called Serenus Dreamers roughly a year ago. I went looking for it as I recall reading it at least 7 years ago.

It's about a beautiful girl with long black hair and short bangs, and a guy with light hair. I think they met on vacation in an ice ski resort and fall in love as they meet. The artwork is extremely beautiful, close to Miyasaka Kaho's work but it isn't one of her works.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the manga you are looking for is **Kiss And Never Cry**.

[image]

- The **Scanlator** is **Serenus Dreamers**
- The **Story** is - Michiru is a happy child who loves to skate.
  During her childhood, she meets Leon, a cute innocent boy. They begin
  to ice dance together. But as she has a conflict with her mom, she
  plans to run away with Leon. Leon, considering the danger, declines
  Michiru. Hurt by this, Michiru runs away by herself. Finding out that
  Michiru has run away, Leon and others search for her, finding her in
  the skating rink. But the Michiru they find standing in the rink no
  longer has the smile that the old Michiru had!?
- The **Credits Page** is -

  [image]
- It's the only manga scanlated by Serenus Dreamers with Ice Sports in it.